# How to store several inputs to an Array in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring MVC and I'm creating a form with several attributes that the user needs to complete and I want to store a list of numbers into an Array and not create a variable for each field

[image]

I try this code, but doesn't work :

```
Linea 1 <form:input type="number" path="numberArray[0]"/>
Linea 2 <form:input type="number" path="numberArray[1]"/>
...
```

Comment: Please add your complete codes

Answer (score 1):

In Spring 3+, `<form:input/>` cannot be used for this because the W3C HTML Specification changed to disallow `[]` in form input `name` attributes. [Here is a good writeup](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/) of using the raw HTML `input` elements to support rows/arrays of fields (it's essentially what you were trying to do with `numberArray[index]` but using the raw HTML `input` element).